# Why was Swift designed to not allow generics for protocols?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols, associated-types

Why didn't the designers of Swift not allow doing:

```
protocol Download<T> {
    var x: T
}
```

and instead force us to do:

```
protocol Download {
    associatedtype: T
    var x: T
}
```

I suppose it's because this way you can restrict/default the associatedtypes, something that isn't possible with generic parameters at the protocol level, but is that all?

Comment: Hah. I forgot all about that other question

Answer (score -1):

This is because the type must be defined before it gets compiled. This is needed because `Swift` is a type-safe language.

Comment: why isn't this true for generics outside of protocols?

Comment: @mfaani Since the guy copy-pasted the answer without really understanding what he is saying, they can't really answer your question